# "Like that" after plural nouns

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it possible to say "like that" in the following sentence?

If I was poor, there would be no way I could afford things **like that**.

Personally, I would say **like these** or **like those**.

Would you help me, please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It depends what *that* refers to. Your sentence does not supply a clue. If I am talking, let's say, about someone's new car then *that* is perfectly correct, since I am referring to that one item. If, on the other hand I am talking about their car, their yacht and their second-home, then I would say "I couldn't possibly afford things like those" - since they are plural in number. The plural "things" is irrelevant since it is not what is being referred to.

Comment: To understand that completely -> I bought an expensive car, a new TV and furniture = If I was poor, there would be no way I could afford things **like those**. 

The only thing I bought is an expensive car =  If I was poor, there would be no way I could afford things **like that**.

Correct?

Comment: Correct. You also use ***those*** if you're referring to multiples of a single type of object, like *books*. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

"*They own a fancy car, a big house and they always go on exotic holidays.  I wish I could afford things like **that***."

It may not follow the rules, but [this is often said](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=things+like+that%2C+things+like+those&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthings%20like%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthings%20like%20those%3B%2Cc0)).  I suppose because the collected items are treated as one impossible to achieve aspiration (in this case).

Comment: Rules that don't evolve to match patterns of usage. Are there rules like that?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - you are pulling my leg surely?  Contributors to this site vary hugely in the extent to which they respect the sanctity of precedent.  Of course rules evolve, but different people accept changes with varying degrees of readiness.

Comment: I'm considering cutting out the jokes.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but only if the antecedent - the subject of the conversation - is singular. The word ***that*** has no referent in the current sentence, so it must be referring to the subject of a prior sentemce, which you have not supplied. It does not refer to “things” in this sentence because it is acting as an adjective modifying it - ***things [like that]***. The things clearly cannot be compared to themselves, so they must be getting compared to something else not named in this sentence. If the “something else” is singular, like a car, or a watch, then we use ***things like that***; if plural, like books or jewels, or if a collection of things, we use ***things like those***.